# how to aligned columns in two rows?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am using two rows. In each row there are two columns of complete size `col-md-12`.in 1st column having 2 fields and the other column has 1 field. Now i put these same 2 in other row. All columns are not aligned: 
here is the snippet:

```html
<div class="row"> 
  <div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="col-md-3">
       <div class="form-group">
            <label for="description">Description</label>
         <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
                                                        <option>Android</option>
                                                        <option>iOS</option>
                                                        <option>Windows</option>
                                                        <option>Symbian</option>
                                                        <option>Atari TOS</option>
                                                        <option>Amiga OS</option>
                                                        <option>Unix</option>
                                                        <option>Linux</option>
                                                        <option>OSX</option>
 </select>
  <div class="input-error form-control-input" style="color: Red; display: none;">Description is required</div>
  </div>
    </div> 
                           
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="group">Issue Date</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="daterange-singe-date-picker" value="10/24/1984">
      <div class="input-error form-control-input" style="color: Red; display: none;">date is required</div>
       </div>

   </div>    
                            
       <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="group">Expiry Date</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="daterange-singe-date-picker" value="10/24/1984">
                <div class="input-error form-control-input" style="color: Red; display: none;">date is required</div>
              </div>
        </div>
                            
                        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="reference">Reference</label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="reference" name="reference" placeholder="Reference">
                                                    <div class="input-error form-control-input" style="color: Red; display: none;">Person is required</div>
                                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                         <div class="form-group">
                           <label for="reference">Reference</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="reference" name="reference" placeholder="Reference">
                            <div class="input-error form-control-input" style="color: Red; display: none;">Person is required</div>
                                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
```

so my question is why bootstrap does not aligned specified rows of columns in my given snippet of code?

Comment: it will work and align element automatically. you check whether your bootstrap.css is linked to your program correctly or not

Comment: check out this link http://jsfiddle.net/71dzp0qy/1/
and to me your bootstrap.css is not properly linked.

Comment: @DeepakVerma bro that's not case. if it is why would the first columns rendered properly ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like this? I can't recall if bootstrap does this for you. I am sorry if I misinterpreted the question.

```css
label {
display:table;
width:90px;
float:left;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row"> 
  <div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="col-md-3">
       <div class="form-group">
            <label for="description">Description</label>
         <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
                                                        <option>Android</option>
                                                        <option>iOS</option>
                                                        <option>Windows</option>
                                                        <option>Symbian</option>
                                                        <option>Atari TOS</option>
                                                        <option>Amiga OS</option>
                                                        <option>Unix</option>
                                                        <option>Linux</option>
                                                        <option>OSX</option>
 </select>
  <div class="input-error form-control-input" style="color: Red; display: none;">Description is required</div>
  </div>
    </div> 
                           
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="group">Issue Date</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="daterange-singe-date-picker" value="10/24/1984">
      <div class="input-error form-control-input" style="color: Red; display: none;">date is required</div>
       </div>

   </div>    
                            
       <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="group">Expiry Date</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="daterange-singe-date-picker" value="10/24/1984">
                <div class="input-error form-control-input" style="color: Red; display: none;">date is required</div>
              </div>
        </div>
                            
                        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="reference">Reference</label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="reference" name="reference" placeholder="Reference">
                                                    <div class="input-error form-control-input" style="color: Red; display: none;">Person is required</div>
                                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                         <div class="form-group">
                           <label for="reference">Reference</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="reference" name="reference" placeholder="Reference">
                            <div class="input-error form-control-input" style="color: Red; display: none;">Person is required</div>
                                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="row"> 
  <div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="col-md-3">
       <div class="form-group">
            <label for="description">Description</label>
         <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
                                                        <option>Android</option>
                                                        <option>iOS</option>
                                                        <option>Windows</option>
                                                        <option>Symbian</option>
                                                        <option>Atari TOS</option>
                                                        <option>Amiga OS</option>
                                                        <option>Unix</option>
                                                        <option>Linux</option>
                                                        <option>OSX</option>
 </select>
  <div class="input-error form-control-input" style="color: Red; display: none;">Description is required</div>
  </div>
    </div> 
                           
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="group">Issue Date</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="daterange-singe-date-picker" value="10/24/1984">
      <div class="input-error form-control-input" style="color: Red; display: none;">date is required</div>
       </div>

   </div>    
                            
       <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="group">Expiry Date</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="daterange-singe-date-picker" value="10/24/1984">
                <div class="input-error form-control-input" style="color: Red; display: none;">date is required</div>
              </div>
        </div>
                            
                        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="reference">Reference</label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="reference" name="reference" placeholder="Reference">
                                                    <div class="input-error form-control-input" style="color: Red; display: none;">Person is required</div>
                                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                         <div class="form-group">
                           <label for="reference">Reference</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="reference" name="reference" placeholder="Reference">
                            <div class="input-error form-control-input" style="color: Red; display: none;">Person is required</div>
                                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>   
 
</body>
```

This code is just a copy of your code snippet, i just placed a CDN Link to bootstrap CSS which aligned everthing for me

Answer (score 0):

I hope this could help.
N.B. I think you have got two `</div>` tag that should not be there (Please check comments in my example) also keep in mind that you should have unique id (not relevant according with your question but it might be helpful, I hope)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="description">Description</label>
        <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
          <option>Android</option>
          <option>iOS</option>
          <option>Windows</option>
          <option>Symbian</option>
          <option>Atari TOS</option>
          <option>Amiga OS</option>
          <option>Unix</option>
          <option>Linux</option>
          <option>OSX</option>
        </select>
        <div class="input-error form-control-input" style="color: Red; display: none;">Description is required</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="group">Issue Date</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="daterange-singe-date-picker" value="10/24/1984">
        <div class="input-error form-control-input" style="color: Red; display: none;">date is required</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="group">Expiry Date</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="daterange-singe-date-picker" value="10/24/1984">
        <div class="input-error form-control-input" style="color: Red; display: none;">date is required</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="reference">Reference</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="reference" name="reference" placeholder="Reference">
        <div class="input-error form-control-input" style="color: Red; display: none;">Person is required</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--</div>  you should delete this closing div -->
 
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="reference">Reference</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="reference" name="reference" placeholder="Reference">
        <div class="input-error form-control-input" style="color: Red; display: none;">Person is required</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--</div>  you should delete this closing div -->
```